# Update script with batching doesnt stop executing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We have the following update script we are trying to do in batches.

Currently the execution never stops running - so needed help understanding what's wrong with the logic or syntax that's missing.

```
--Create Temp table

CREATE TABLE #TempIFSC ([EnrolledPaymentMethodAccountId] uniqueidentifier,
                        [PaymentAccountId] uniqueidentifier,
                        [ExternalSystemId] int,
                        [EnrolledPaymentMethodAccountStatusId] int,
                        [Extension] xml,
                        [EnrollmentAccountRevisionId] int,
                        [BankName] nvarchar(100) NULL,
                        [BankBranch] nvarchar(100) NULL,
                        [IFSC] nvarchar(100) NULL);

--Insert record into temp table who does not have IFSC code and currency INR

INSERT INTO #TempIFSC
SELECT EP.[EnrolledPaymentMethodAccountId],
       EP.[PaymentAccountId],
       EP.[ExternalSystemId],
       EP.[EnrolledPaymentMethodAccountStatusId],
       CAST(EP.[Extension] AS xml),
       EP.[EnrollmentAccountRevisionId],
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM [dbo].[EnrolledPaymentMethodAccount] EP WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[PaymentAccount] PA WITH (NOLOCK) ON EP.PaymentAccountId = PA.PaymentAccountId
                                                       AND PA.CurrencyCode = 'INR'
WHERE ISNULL(CAST(EP.Extension AS xml).value('(//*[local-name()="Value"])[6]', 'NVARCHAR(255)'), '') = ''
  AND EP.ExternalSystemId = 52
  AND EP.EnrolledPaymentMethodAccountStatusId = 1;

--Update the BankName and BankBranch value in temp table

DECLARE @Rowcount int = 1;

WHILE (@Rowcount > 0)
BEGIN

    UPDATE TOP (4999)
        #TempIFSC
    SET BankName = b.Name,
        BankBranch = TMP.Extension.value('(//*[local-name()="Value"])[3]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    FROM #TempIFSC TMP
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[Bank] b ON b.ExternalSystembankId = TMP.Extension.value('(//*[local-name()="Value"])[2]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    WHERE b.ExternalSystemId = TMP.ExternalSystemId
      AND b.CurrencyCode = 'INR';

    SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;

    PRINT @Rowcount;

    CHECKPOINT;

END;

--Update IFSC value in temp table

DECLARE @IFSCRowcount int = 1;

WHILE (@IFSCRowcount > 0)
BEGIN

    UPDATE TOP (4999)
        #TempIFSC
    SET IFSC = IM.IFSC
    FROM #TempIFSC TMP
         INNER JOIN [taurus].[IFSCMasterList] IM (NOLOCK) ON TMP.BankBranch = IM.BankBranchName
                                                         AND TMP.BankName = IM.BankName;

    SET @IFSCRowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;

    CHECKPOINT; --<-- to commit the changes with each batch

END;

--Remove blank node of IFSC

DECLARE @XMLRowcount int = 1;

WHILE (@XMLRowcount > 0)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @NodeName nvarchar(500) = N'NameValueEntity';

    UPDATE TOP (4999)
        #TempIFSC
    SET Extension.modify('delete /ArrayOfNameValueEntity/*[local-name(.) eq sql:variable("@NodeName")][6]')
    FROM #TempIFSC
    WHERE Extension.exist(N'/*/NameValueEntity/Name[text()="IFSCCode"]') = 1
      AND ISNULL(Extension.value('(//*[local-name()="Value"])[6]', 'NVARCHAR(255)'), '') = '';

    SET @XMLRowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;

    PRINT @XMLRowcount;

    CHECKPOINT; --<-- to commit the changes with each batch

END;

--Update extension value in temp table

DECLARE @CodeRowcount int = 1;

WHILE (@CodeRowcount > 0)
BEGIN

    UPDATE TOP (4999)
        #TempIFSC
    SET Extension.modify('insert <NameValueEntity><Name>IFSCCode</Name><Value>{sql:column("#TempIFSC.IFSC")}</Value></NameValueEntity>

into (/ArrayOfNameValueEntity)[1]')
    FROM #TempIFSC
    WHERE ISNULL(IFSC, '') <> '';

    SET @CodeRowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;

    CHECKPOINT; --<-- to commit the changes with each batch

END;
```

Comment: That’s not what CHECKPOINT does.

Comment: At least *one* of those `WHILE` loops is looping infinitely. The last one almost certainly will be, as you alter the value of `Extension` but check if the value of `IFSC` isn't the value `''`; so you'll likely be updating the same arbitary 4999 rows over and over and over and over and... over and over... and over... and over... again.

Comment: As a side note, `WHERE ISNULL(IFSC, '') <> ''` isn't a good `WHERE` clause as it's not SARGable. It should be `WHERE IFSC <> '' OR IFCS IS NULL`

Comment: Your first `UPDATE` is going to loop infinitely as well, provided there is at least 1 row updated in the first iteration.

Comment: Finally, those `NOLOCK` hints when using DML statements are normally a strong sign of not understanding what that hint does; unless you are happy with potentionally (very) wrong results in yout table(s)? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Also you are checkpointing the wrong database anyway as temp tables live in tempdb. And `(//*[local-name()="Value"])[6]` has to be the absolute slowest way to do XQuery. You should probably do something like `(/SomeNode/Value/text())[1]`. How about you show us what you are *really* trying to do with that XQuery, I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Have updated the original question with your comments - struggling to understand how to use SE. Its not the most friendly.
All but the last while loop is working.
How can i post the part that isnt working still

Comment: thanks all for help - have implemented all suggestions and working much better now